# Custom lexer/parser-based code prettifier

Tags: c#, html, formatting, rubberduck, antlr

I'm adding rather extensive xml-doc comments to all Rubberduck inspection classes, like this:

```
namespace Rubberduck.Inspections.Concrete
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Warns about a variable that is assigned, and then re-assigned before the first assignment is read.
    /// </summary>
    /// <why>
    /// The first assignment is likely redundant, since it is being overwritten by the second.
    /// </why>
    /// <examples>
    /// <example>
    /// <text>This inspection means to flag the following examples:</text>
    /// <code>
    /// <![CDATA[
    /// Public Sub DoSomething()
    ///     Dim foo As Long
    ///     foo = 12 ' assignment is redundant
    ///     foo = 34 
    /// End Sub]]>
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    /// <example>
    /// <text>The following code should not trip this inspection:</text>
    /// <code>
    /// <![CDATA[
    /// Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal foo As Long)
    ///     Dim bar As Long
    ///     bar = 12
    ///     bar = bar + foo ' variable is re-assigned, but the prior assigned value is read at least once first.
    /// End Sub]]>
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    /// </examples>
    public sealed class AssignmentNotUsedInspection : InspectionBase
    {
        ...
```

The idea being to get our CI server to build the XML docs for that assembly, and then essentially use the GitHub repository as a CDN to retrieve and parse from the project's website - and that works great: on my local build I generate the `/inspections/list` page contents off the XML documentation, exactly as intended.

But the `/list` page doesn't include the `<examples>`; I want the `/inspections/details/{inspection-name}` pages to include them, and I want them not only formatted as code, but also syntax-highlighted  - similar to how the site's [404 error page](http://rubberduckvba.com/Error/PageNotFound) formats some dummy VBA code, but better: that dummy code's CSS formatting is all hard-coded, and there's no way I'm going to clutter the xml-doc examples with `<span class="keyword">` tags.

Since Rubberduck's VBA parser does a pretty awesome job at parsing VBA code, I figured it shouldn't be too hard to write a class that takes this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim foo As Long
    foo = 12 ' assignment is redundant
    foo = 34
End Sub
```

...and outputs this:

```html
<span class="keyword">Public</span> <span class="keyword">Sub</span> DoSomething()
    <span class="keyword">Dim</span> foo <span class="keyword">As</span> <span class="keyword">Long</span>
    foo = 12 <span class="comment">' assignment is redundant
</span>    foo = 34
<span class="keyword">End Sub</span>
```

Here's the class in question:

```
public class FormattedCodeBlockBuilder
{
    private static readonly string KeywordClass = "keyword";
    private static readonly string CommentClass = "comment";
    private static readonly string StringLiteralClass = "string-literal";

    public string Format(string code)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder(code.Length);
        var tokens = Tokenize(code);

        var parser = new VBAParser(tokens);
        var commentsListener = new CommentIntervalsListener();
        parser.AddParseListener(commentsListener);

        parser.startRule();

        for (var i = 0; i < tokens.Size; i++)
        {
            var token = tokens.Get(i);
            if (commentsListener.IsComment(token, out var commentInterval))
            {
                builder.Append($"<span class=\"{CommentClass}\">{tokens.GetText(commentInterval)}</span>");
                i = commentInterval.b;
            }
            else if (StringLiteralTokens.Contains(token.Type))
            {
                builder.Append($"<span class=\"{StringLiteralClass}\">{token.Text}</span>");
            }
            else if (KeywordTokens.Contains(token.Type))
            {
                builder.Append($"<span class=\"{KeywordClass}\">{token.Text}</span>");
            }
            else
            {
                builder.Append(token.Text);
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    private ITokenStream Tokenize(string code)
    {
        AntlrInputStream input;
        using (var reader = new StringReader(code))
        {
            input = new AntlrInputStream(reader);
        }
        var lexer = new VBALexer(input);
        return new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    }

    #region token classes
    private static readonly HashSet<int> StringLiteralTokens = new HashSet<int>
    {
        VBAParser.STRINGLITERAL,
        VBAParser.DATELITERAL,
    };
    private static readonly HashSet<int> KeywordTokens = new HashSet<int> { 
        VBAParser.ANY,
        VBAParser.CURRENCY,
        VBAParser.DEBUG,
        VBAParser.DOEVENTS,
        VBAParser.EXIT,
        VBAParser.FIX,
        VBAParser.INPUTB,
        VBAParser.LBOUND,
        VBAParser.LONGLONG,
        VBAParser.LONGPTR,
        VBAParser.OPTION,
        VBAParser.PSET,
        VBAParser.SCALE,
        VBAParser.SGN,
        VBAParser.UBOUND,
        VBAParser.ACCESS,
        VBAParser.ADDRESSOF,
        VBAParser.ALIAS,
        VBAParser.AND,
        VBAParser.ATTRIBUTE,
        VBAParser.APPEND,
        VBAParser.AS,
        VBAParser.BEGINPROPERTY,
        VBAParser.BEGIN,
        VBAParser.BINARY,
        VBAParser.BOOLEAN,
        VBAParser.BYVAL,
        VBAParser.BYREF,
        VBAParser.BYTE,
        VBAParser.CALL,
        VBAParser.CASE,
        VBAParser.CDECL,
        VBAParser.CLASS,
        VBAParser.CLOSE,
        VBAParser.CONST,
        VBAParser.CONST,
        VBAParser.DATABASE,
        VBAParser.DATE,
        VBAParser.DECLARE,
        VBAParser.DEFBOOL,
        VBAParser.DEFBYTE,
        VBAParser.DEFDATE,
        VBAParser.DEFDBL,
        VBAParser.DEFCUR,
        VBAParser.DEFINT,
        VBAParser.DEFLNG,
        VBAParser.DEFLNGLNG,
        VBAParser.DEFLNGPTR,
        VBAParser.DEFOBJ,
        VBAParser.DEFSNG,
        VBAParser.DEFSTR,
        VBAParser.DEFVAR,
        VBAParser.DIM,
        VBAParser.DO,
        VBAParser.DOUBLE,
        VBAParser.EACH,
        VBAParser.ELSE,
        VBAParser.ELSEIF,
        VBAParser.EMPTY,
        VBAParser.END_ENUM,
        VBAParser.END_FUNCTION,
        VBAParser.END_IF,
        VBAParser.ENDPROPERTY,
        VBAParser.END_SELECT,
        VBAParser.END_SUB,
        VBAParser.END_TYPE,
        VBAParser.END_WITH,
        VBAParser.END,
        VBAParser.ENUM,
        VBAParser.EQV,
        VBAParser.ERASE,
        VBAParser.ERROR,
        VBAParser.EVENT,
        VBAParser.EXIT_DO,
        VBAParser.EXIT_FOR,
        VBAParser.EXIT_FUNCTION,
        VBAParser.EXIT_PROPERTY,
        VBAParser.EXIT_SUB,
        VBAParser.FALSE,
        VBAParser.FRIEND,
        VBAParser.FOR,
        VBAParser.FUNCTION,
        VBAParser.GET,
        VBAParser.GLOBAL,
        VBAParser.GOSUB,
        VBAParser.GOTO,
        VBAParser.IF,
        VBAParser.IMP,
        VBAParser.IMPLEMENTS,
        VBAParser.IN,
        VBAParser.INPUT,
        VBAParser.IS,
        VBAParser.INTEGER,
        VBAParser.LOCK,
        VBAParser.LONG,
        VBAParser.LOOP,
        VBAParser.LET,
        VBAParser.LIB,
        VBAParser.LIKE,
        VBAParser.LINE_INPUT,
        VBAParser.LOCK_READ,
        VBAParser.LOCK_WRITE,
        VBAParser.LOCK_READ_WRITE,
        VBAParser.LSET,
        VBAParser.MOD,
        VBAParser.NAME,
        VBAParser.NEXT,
        VBAParser.NEW,
        VBAParser.NOT,
        VBAParser.NOTHING,
        VBAParser.NULL,
        VBAParser.OBJECT,
        VBAParser.ON_ERROR,
        VBAParser.ON_LOCAL_ERROR,
        VBAParser.OPEN,
        VBAParser.OPTIONAL,
        VBAParser.OPTION_BASE,
        VBAParser.OPTION_EXPLICIT,
        VBAParser.OPTION_COMPARE,
        VBAParser.OPTION_PRIVATE_MODULE,
        VBAParser.OR,
        VBAParser.OUTPUT,
        VBAParser.PARAMARRAY,
        VBAParser.PRESERVE,
        VBAParser.PRINT,
        VBAParser.PRIVATE,
        VBAParser.PROPERTY_GET,
        VBAParser.PROPERTY_LET,
        VBAParser.PROPERTY_SET,
        VBAParser.PTRSAFE,
        VBAParser.PUBLIC,
        VBAParser.PUT,
        VBAParser.RANDOM,
        VBAParser.RANDOMIZE,
        VBAParser.RAISEEVENT,
        VBAParser.READ,
        VBAParser.READ_WRITE,
        VBAParser.REDIM,
        VBAParser.REM,
        VBAParser.RESET,
        VBAParser.RESUME,
        VBAParser.RETURN,
        VBAParser.RSET,
        VBAParser.SEEK,
        VBAParser.SELECT,
        VBAParser.SET,
        VBAParser.SHARED,
        VBAParser.SINGLE,
        VBAParser.STATIC,
        VBAParser.STEP,
        VBAParser.STOP,
        VBAParser.STRING,
        VBAParser.SUB,
        VBAParser.TAB,
        VBAParser.TEXT,
        VBAParser.THEN,
        VBAParser.TO,
        VBAParser.TRUE,
        VBAParser.TYPE,
        VBAParser.TYPEOF,
        VBAParser.UNLOCK,
        VBAParser.UNTIL,
        VBAParser.VARIANT,
        VBAParser.VERSION,
        VBAParser.WEND,
        VBAParser.WITH,
        VBAParser.WITHEVENTS,
        VBAParser.WRITE,
        VBAParser.XOR
    };
    #endregion

    private class CommentIntervalsListener : VBAParserBaseListener
    {
        private readonly IList<Interval> _intervals = new List<Interval>();

        public bool IsComment(IToken token, out Interval commentInterval)
        {
            if (!_intervals.Any())
            {
                commentInterval = Interval.Invalid;
                return false;
            }

            var tokenInterval = new Interval(token.TokenIndex, token.TokenIndex);
            commentInterval = _intervals.SingleOrDefault(e => e.ProperlyContains(tokenInterval));
            return !commentInterval.Equals(default(Interval));
        }

        public override void ExitCommentOrAnnotation(VBAParser.CommentOrAnnotationContext context)
        {
            _intervals.Add(context.SourceInterval);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anything strike anyone as weird or wrong in that string formatter class? I don't do web stuff very often, so this might very well be a very naive approach to building the formatted HTML. If it's any relevant, the website is ASP.NET MVC (not Core, since it's referencing the `Rubberduck.SmartIndender` and `Rubberduck.Parsing` assemblies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically building a compiler. You have your tokenizer and parser available, but your target language generator is missing. Sure, hardcoding in html can be done for a small use case, but I would prefer to use an existing API.

Suggested API: [`HtmlTextWriter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) from System.Web.

Alternative API: [`HtmlElement`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement?view=netframework-4.8) from System.Windows.Forms.

Both API's allow building html elements in code and back- and forward mapping between managed code and html text.

Comment: The `System.Windows.Forms` namespace would be the last place I would ever look for a `HtmlElement` :-o How did they come up with the idea to _hide_ it there? Oh boy.

Comment: @t3chb0t good point - but I like the idea of building the HTML with that kind of object rather than concatenating/building a string. Surely `System.Web` has a similar DOM classes somewhere, right?

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon: check out https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8, I will update my post